# Purpose of customized data types?

Tags: haskell, types

This is a simple question, but one I'm still unsure about. What is the main benefit(s) of having customized types in Haskell, such as:

```
data Users a = User a a a 
data Towns a = TownA Int | TownB String | Nill
```

Is the main use of these custom types to act like objects in imperative languages? Such as

```
template<typename U>
class User 
{
  U a1;
  U a2;
  U a3;
};

int main()
{
  User<std::string> UserObj; UserObj.a1="a1"; //etc
}
```

Does anyone have a brief and general explanation?

---

N.B I understand the usefulness of binary types such as Maybe, my question is more about the use of custom types.

Comment: Your C++ example doesn't show any objects. While `User` is not officially a type, `User<int>` is a type and not an object. So if your question is whether Haskell types are used the same way C++ types are used, then the answer is "by and large, yes".

Comment: Your `Users a` type in Haskell roughly corresponds to your `User<A>` type in C++. I wonder why custom types surprise you, they can be declared in many programming languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without considering the types you quote specifically [1], I think we can talk about three main kinds of benefits:

### Restricting your power

As an arbitrary example, pick your `Users` type. Rather than defining a separate data type, you might try just using a list instead. Perhaps you might even use `type` to provide a type synonym and make it a little prettier:

```
type Users a = [a]
makeUsers u1 u2 u3 = [u1, u2, u3]
```

However, if your original definition was `data Users a = Users a a a`, it is reasonable to assume that there being three fields in the data type isn't fruit of an arbitrary choice, but that it was so because there being three users in each set is a relevant condition you want to enforce. If `Users` is a list, however, it is trivial to break that by changing the number of elements in the list:

```
us1 = makeUsers "Jack" "Eric" "Ginger"
us2 = drop 1 us1 -- Oops!
```

If you define the type as you originally proposed, however, such an accident becomes impossible, as there is no way of creating that `Users` with more or less than three fields. In general, a custom type gives you much better control over what you, or anyone else, can do with the values of the type. Other similar moves include not exporting constructors and field names for a custom type (which has roughly the same effect of making fields private in something like C++) and not writing instances for classes you don't want to actually use.

### Increasing your power

Given what we said above, someone might think of making `Users` a 3-tuple instead -- after all, that is guaranteed to hold three elements:

```
type Users a = (a, a, a)
makeUsers u1 u2 u3 = (u1, u2, u3)
```

That is certainly an improvement. However, let's say you want, for whatever reason, to apply a function to all three values in an `Users`. If `Users` were a `Functor`, you could simply use `fmap`:

```
us1' = fmap reverse us
```

However, there is no `Functor` instance for homogeneous 3-tuples, and writing in your own code an instance of a class when both class and type are defined in some other library (the jargon term for that is "orphan instance") is almost always a terrible idea. So you are stuck with writing a class-less map function, with a name of its own:

```
mapUsers :: (a -> b) -> Users a -> Users b
mapUsers f (Users u1 u2 u3) = Users (f u1) (f u2) (f u3)
```

Doing that all the time, however, gets old quickly, pollutes your namespace with a lot of unneeded names and, worst of all, prevents you from using all the machinery in other libraries which expects an instance of `Functor`, as opposed to some arbitrary type which happens to have a `fmap`-like function defined for it. If you have a custom type, though, you can provide the instance just fine:

```
instance Functor Users where
    fmap f (Users u1 u2 u3) = Users (f u1) (f u2) (f u3)
```

(By the way, I should mention there is a tool in the language which covers precisely the case in which you would like to use a preexisting type but with new or different instances: the keyword `newtype`. But that is for another, future, question.)

### Clarifying your code

Finally, there is the benefit of custom types with custom names (and custom field names, if you use record syntax) making it far more obvious what each value you are using is actually meant for, which is certainly a very significant gain.

---

As chi points out in a comment, these benefits apply to any language with types. Given how powerful Haskell's type system is, however, the advantages brought by defining your own types well are larger than in most other languages.

---

[1]: Though if you were actually using that `Towns a` you probably should remove the missing value placeholder `Nill`...

```
data Town = TownA String | TownB Int
```

... and use `Maybe Town` instead of `Town` in the cases you would need `Nill`.

Comment: "and writing in your own code an instance for a type defined in some other library (the jargon term for that is "orphan instance") is almost always a terrible idea" You missed the condition that the class also has to be defined in some other library.

Comment: @duplode can you explain further using Maybe to replace Nil? I don't quite understand...

Comment: @BabraCunningham If you were using `Nill` as a placeholder for a missing town, it is better to not make it part of the type `Town`, as a non-existent town is not a town. After doing that, you can use `Maybe Town` instead of `Town` when missing values are possible (e.g. `Just "Cheltenham"` versus `Nothing`), and just use `Town` when they aren't. That is both more precise (as you know just from the type when a the value might be missing) and more convenient (you don't have to bother with a `Nill` case if there is no way the value might be missing). I have updated the answer.

Comment: (In the comment above it should be `Just (TownA "Cheltenham")` rather than `Just "Cheltenham"`, of course.)